# Evaluation of Operator-Valued Function

Tags: real-analysis, operator-theory, quantum-mechanics

[image: Question]

Hello all; above is my question! :)

I've gone through all the way up to the final *"and hence deduce that"*. Up to this point, the question has been fairly straightforward, but I have no idea how to deduce the final equalities from the derivative.

I know that it is possible to show that $f(z) = e^z e^w e^{-(z+w)}$, for fixed $w$, has $f'(z) = 0$ for all $z$, and as such is constant. Choosing $z = -w$ gives $f(-w) = 1$, and as such $f(z) = 1$ for all $z$; therefore, $e^z e^w = e^{z+w}$.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to adapt this for operator-valued functions (since the derivative isn't $0$); I don't even know if this is the right approach for operator-valued functions.

As always, assistance, not just the answer, is most appreciated!

Comment: Look at it like this: You're looking for an operator which, if you differentiate it with respect to $\lambda$, gives you the original operator times $\lambda[A,B]$. You've got one operator which satisfies that already; can you find a second one?

Comment: Well, $\exp(\lambda [A,B])$?

Comment: Not quite. That'd just give you $F'(\lambda)=[A,B]F(\lambda).$ But something seems off---let me think through this a bit more.

Comment: No, sorry, $\exp({1 \over 2} \lambda^2 [A,B])$. So the two are equal up to a constant. Set $\lambda = 0$ to see that the additive constant is $0$ and $\lambda = 1$ to get the first result, since $A$ and $B$ commute with $[A,B]$ so can combine the exponentials.

Comment: Nice job! I had forgotten you were allowed to assume they commuted with the commutator. As for the last, the same reasoning that showed that $F(\lambda)$ worked should allow you to conclude that this version also works.

Comment: That only shows the first though... do I just come up with another function for the next part, do you think?

Comment: Or just let $G(\lambda)$ be the same, but with $A$ and $B$ swapped (but still $A+B = B+A$), so the derivative is the same but negative, then do the same, noting that we can take ${1 \over 2}[A,B]$ from each side of the exponentials and maintain the second equality.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16007/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-smiley-sam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Reposted from comments at questioner's suggestion)

Hint: You're looking for an operator which, if you differentiate it with respect to $\lambda$, gives you the original operator times $\lambda[A,B]$. You've got one operator which satisfies that already; can you find a second one?

Comment: Perfect, thank you! :)